# Were there cooks for the gods on Olympus in Greek(or Roman) Mythology

Tags: greek, roman, olympus

I am writing a play in which Greek mythology is a worshipful act and wanted to write that the gods decided to eat the humanly harvest rather than the food (ambrosia, the nectar) of Olympus.

Are there any "godly" considered cooks or gods of banquets, rich foods, etc. in Greek (or Roman) Mythology? And if anything, more distinctly, was there a god who prepared the ambrosia for Jupiter and Juna on Mount Olympus?

Answer (score 5):

### [Hebe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebe_(mythology))

Hebe was the cup-bearer and poured ambrosia and nectar of the gods. You might know her better as the wife of Hercules, who upon his ascension to Mount Olympus "got" her from his enemy and her mother Hera as reconciliation.

> "Now the gods at the side of Zeus were sitting in council over the golden floor, and among them the goddess Hebe (Youth) poured them nectar as wine, while they in the golden drinking-cups drank to each other, gazing down on the city of the Trojans."<sub>Homer, Iliad 4</sub>

### [Ganymede](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ganymede_(mythology))

After the marriage between Hercules and Hebe Ganymede became the next cup-bearer.

> "Verily wise Zeus carried off golden-haired Ganymedes (Ganymede) because of his beauty, to be amongst the Deathless Ones and pour drink for the gods in the house of Zeus--a wonder to see--, honoured by all the immortals as he draws the red nectar from the golden bowl deathless and unageing, even as the gods." <sub>Homeric Hymn 5 to Aphrodite 203</sub>

.

> "He that pours wine for Zeus [Ganymedes] was an oxherd."
>   <sub>Nonnus, Dionysiaca 15. 279</sub>

.

> Ganymede was the loveliest born of the race of mortals, and therefore
>   the gods caught him away to themselves, to be Zeus' wine-pourer,
>   for the sake of his beauty, so he might be among the immortals. <sub>Homer, Iliad, Book 20</sub>

### [Juventus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juventas)

Juventus was the Roman equivalent to Hebe and Ganymede

> "What viands and beverages, what harmonies of music and flowers of
>   various hue, what delights of touch and smell will you assign to the
>   gods, so as to keep them steeped in pleasure? The poets array banquets
>   or nectar and ambrosia, with Juventas (Hebe or Ganymede) in attendance
>   as cup-bearer." <sub>Cicero, De Natura Deorum 1. 40</sub>

Answer (score 4):

In the book Odyssey, it's said that ambrosia was carried to Olympus by doves [1]:

> Here not even a bird may pass, no, not even **the timid doves that bring ambrosia  to  Father  Jove**,  but  the  sheer  rock  always  carries  off one of them, and Father Jove has to send another to make up their number

Also, Demeter was considered the goddess of crops and agriculture, being intrinsically linked to food.
The Roman goddess counterpart is Ceres. [2]

Ceraon, Deipneo and Matton are greek semi-gods related to food. More specifically the bread preparation stages.

To Romans, Abundantia was the personification of abundance, carring the Cornucopia - presented as a large horn-shaped container overflowing with produce, flowers, or nuts [3][4]

---

*References*

[1] HOMER. The Odyssey. 1:Translated by Samuel Butler. p. 202.

[2] FINLEY, M. I.. The World of Odysseus. 4. ed. New York: New Yorknyrb Classics, 2002.

[4] Apollodorus. The Library of Greek Mythology. 1. ed. Oxford University Press, 2008.

[4] PARKER, R. Polytheism and Society at Athens. OUP Oxford, 2005.

Answer (score 1):

Demeter was the goddess of the harvest and often put on banquets for the gods and sometimes mortals. You also have Pan who was worshipped as the "party god" and/or Dionysus God of the vine.

Comment: Demeter was the goddess of harvest I thought.

Comment: @dean1957 your right, Hecate was goddess of magic, witchcraft, etc. Demeter is the Goddess of the Harvest

Answer (score 0):

**Ganymede** was a Trojan prince. Zeus turned into an eagle and kidnapped the prince, eventually bringing him to the Mount Olympus and giving him the title of the cup-bearer. Ganymede then provided the Gods with ambrosia - drink which made the Gods immortal - in his Crater (cup). In mosaic art Ganymede is shown as a handsome young boy surrounded by Aquila (Zeus as an eagle), holding his Crater.

https://www.theoi.com/Ouranios/Ganymedes.html via Homer ( Homer's Iliad) and Hesoid (Catalogues of Women Frag)

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site, thank you for your contribution. Unfortunately Ganymede has already been mentioned in an answer to this question (coincidentally mine ;) ).